Streaming Data from Azure Databricks to MongoDB Atlas
I am attempting to create a streaming job to write data to MongoDB, but I am encountering an error indicating that MongoDB does not support streaming jobs.
My compute version is
14.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.5.0, Scala 2.12)
and my spark connector version is
org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1
My code to write the data is as below
json_df.writeStream \
    .format("mongo") \
    .option("uri", mongo_uri) \
    .option("database", "test_db") \
    .option("collection", "test") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .trigger(processingTime="1 minute") \
    .start()

the error that I get is

Data source mongo does not support streamed writing.

Is there a driver or library available for writing streaming data to MongoDB using Databricks?
Note: The standard read and write operations from Databricks to MongoDB are functioning correctly.

As you mention you have already used org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1
As you mention need library to driver or library available for writing streaming data to MongoDB using Databricks?
Know more about MongoDB - Azure Databricks MongoDB Connector for Spark Documentation.
Version 10.x utilizes the new namespace com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.MongoTableProvider.
This change enables the use of older connector versions (3.x and earlier) concurrently with version 10.x.
Using the connector, you can use all Spark libraries with MongoDB datasets, including:

Dataset: For SQL analysis with automatic schema inference.
Streaming: For real-time data processing.

You can try installing the below:
org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.13:10.3.0


And for WriteStream:
dsw = (
  slidingWindows
    .writeStream
    .format("mongodb")
    .queryName("7DaySlidingWindow")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/pyspark/")
    .option("forceDeleteTempCheckpointLocation", "true")
    .option('spark.mongodb.connection.uri', 'MONGODB CONNECTION HERE')
    .option('spark.mongodb.database', 'Pricing')
    .option('spark.mongodb.collection', 'NaturalGas')
    .outputMode("complete"))
query = dsw.start()
query.processAllAvailable()
query.stop()

Reference: MongoDB Connector for Spark
How to sink streaming data from spark to Mongodb?
